# css form input corner box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div to align with the bottom corner of a form input but with a triangular arrow pointing to the corner and merged into the box. I am having problems creating this as i am not a designer. Basically what i'm looking for is a kind of arrow that merges with the box (maybe like a speech bubble)

Anyway code so far:

html:

```
<div class="inputwrap">
     <select id="gb_contact" name="gb_contact" class="dropdown-input" >
            <option value="option">option</option>  
    </select>

    <div class="tip">rrrrrrrrrrr</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.inputwrap{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 10%;
}

.tip:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0 0;
    border-color: #00FF00 transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index: 100;
    left: -0px;
    top: -2px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(5deg);

}

.tip {
    position: absolute;
    right: -190px;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    min-width:200px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-top:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

can anyone help with this?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d30top88/

link to concept:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ZIIks7bG2QT2haMWZZcXM3ZWc/edit?usp=sharing

close enough i suppose :

http://jsfiddle.net/d30top88/4/

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with merged inside the box? Just adjusted your fiddle like that:

[Arrow Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/d30top88/1/)

with some adjustments:

```
top: 12px;
-ms-transform: rotate(135deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(135deg);
```

So it the arrow is now pointed to the right and down in the div.

Update after image link was provided in question:

[Arrow Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/d30top88/3/)

But based on the image maybe the arrow has not the appropriate shape to meet your requirements. There are some nice css arrow generators online, just google for "css arrow generator" as I don't want to promote a special one.

Comment: sorry if it wasnt clear. the sharp edge points to the form element and the wide side becomes part of the box, ill try and find a example of it.

Comment: @David Or you just play around a bit with the fiddle changing the values for rotate (same value for all 3), top and left, it's easy done. Think I can guess where you want to have the arrow placed but if you find an example it'd be done quickly.

Comment: It wouldnt be a million miles away as it is. its the right direction, i might try and make it bigger and see..I've pasted a link into the q to give a idea.

Comment: @David Ok, I've also updated my answer, guess you'll get it done. Good luck!

Comment: no problem thanks @matthias, i made it a bit bigger and it looks better so thanks for helping :)